# Draggable doesn't work in custom function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery and jQuery UI.

This works fine:

```
$('.drag').draggable();
```

But not this:

```
function MyFunction() {
  $('.drag').draggable();
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function

Why I can't use jQuery UI in custom function?

Comment: Do you have JQuery UI library implemented properly? If so, make sure it is before the declaration of the function.

Comment: Do you ever call `MyFunction()`?

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath Yes, of course. It wouldn't work otherwise in first example, right?

And I call function of course

Comment: @ShoneTow depends on their location.

Answer (score 0):

See this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyrq3hcp/

```
$('#d1').draggable();

function draggableDiv() {
    $('#d2').draggable();
}
draggableDiv();
```

Both draggable divs are working without any errors. Check your jquery-ui implementation and be sure the function is called after jquery-ui is loaded.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, but I already commented that it was my mistake, but that comment is missing somehow .... Thank you very much, anyway! :)